# Javascript that replaces bracketed text into tags, doesn't work with <style>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a piece of jquery, that replaces brackets `{}` with `<>` that are inside the body:

**JQuery:**

```
window.onload=function() {
$("body").children().html(function (_, html) {
    return html
    .replace(/\{/g,"<")     
     .replace(/b\@/g,"strong")
.replace(/\!/g,"/")
    .replace(/\}/g,">");
});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tags.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
<w>
<style>
.red {
color: red;
}
</style>
{style}
body {
background-color:red;
}
{!style}

{b@ class="red"}
Some Bold Text
{!b@}

</w>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try putting in a `{style}` tag substitiute, the style tags work, but no CSS is actually rendered. Also I when I try applying the `color:red` in an normal style tag to the `.red {b@}`  it doesn't work, but it works if I apply the style inline.

The question is: Is there any way to make the CSS render properly inside the style tags?

Comment: Its because the `body {
background-color:red;
}` becomes `body <
background-color:red;
>`

Comment: Style tags aren't allowed in the body, they have to be in the head.

Comment: @Barmar Unless they are scoped, or inside a template.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.  You just need to add these lines at the end of your code:

```
$('style').appendTo('head').text(function() {
  return $(this).text().replace(/\</g,'{').replace(/\>/g,'}');
});
```

This moves the `style` elements to the `head`, and it undoes the text substitutions in your previous code for those elements.

**Snippet:**

```js
window.onload=function() {
  $("body").children().html(function (_, html) {
    return html
    .replace(/\{/g,"<")     
     .replace(/b\@/g,"strong")
.replace(/\!/g,"/")
    .replace(/\}/g,">");
  });

  $('style').appendTo('head').text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\</g,'{').replace(/\>/g,'}');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<w>
<style>
.red {
color: red;
}
</style>
{style}
body {
background-color:yellow;
}
{!style}

{b@ class="red"}
Some Bold Text
{!b@}

</w>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @barmar said, the `{}` were overriding the CSS brackets, so I just changed the `{}` to `[]`, so it wouldn't interfere.

Answer (score -1):

It's because the `<style>` tag hasn't been compiled by the browser since you wrote `{style}`,you can't make it work by replacing `{}` by `<>`.
You need to replace as your script is doing, then load all the code in jquery and append it to the page